# Is it realistic to implement PHP daemon, which will keep a constant connection with websocket-server?

Tags: php, websocket

The essence of the situation:

There website is a call-center (websocket-server located at a site different from the server).

The site must receive relevant information for now with this websoket server, the information received by the site is the same for all users (the number of available telephone lines).

Now it is implemented as follows: each visitor at each transition on the pages connects with websocket-server via javascript and receives the data. As a result, created a large number of compounds and websoket server drops.

Change anything on websoket server is not possible.

How should work:

On the site server running PHP daemon that establishes one connection to vebsoket server and receives every N seconds to date information and writes it to a file.

question:

Is it realistic to implement PHP daemon, which will keep a constant connection with websocket-server? If so, what additional libraries needed for this?

Comment: Edited to make English, but with Google Translate. So, for all I know, it may have originally said "my hovercraft is full of eels" :-)

Comment: i will be careful with google translate. it sometimes changes the whole meaning of a sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is very useful lib with simple examples. Tested on real projects.

https://github.com/lukaszkujawa/php-multithreaded-socket-server

Here is example page

http://systemsarchitect.net/multi-threaded-socket-server-in-php-with-fork